# Increment 3D array of counters from 2D list of indices (x,y,z) using: Python Numpy Slicing

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, slice

I want to increment a 3D matrix (nparray) of counters from a 2D array of events (x,y,t)
The code below works:

```
TOF_cube=np.zeros((324,324,4095),np.int32) #initialise a 3d array for whole data set

data = np.fromfile(f, dtype='<i2', count=no_I16) #read all events, x,y,t as 1D array
data=data.reshape(events,cols)
xpos=data[:,0]
ypos=data[:,1]
tpos=data[:,2]
i=0
while i < events:              
    TOF_cube[xpos[i],ypos[i],tpos[i]] += 1
    i+=1
```

To use slicing and indexing I replace my while loop with

```
    TOF_cube[xpos,ypos,tpos] += 1
```

But rather than copying the correct 4365520 number of events (via the while loop and independently checked) I only record 4365197.

Why is the slicing method loosing events?

I am using exactly the same slices in the while loop and as an 'argument' to the index.

Comment: What is `TOF_cube.max()` for each method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+=` doesn't add twice if there are repeat indices.

To get an equivalent output in a vectorized manner, you'll need [`np.add.at`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html):

```
np.add.at(TOF_cube, [xpos, ypos, tpos], 1)
```

Comment: Thank you!

This was the problem, thank you! I am surprised that 
`np.add.at(TOF_cube, [xpos, ypos, tpos], 1).`

seems to run a lot slower than the += version. (I know I was missing some events, but very few). One would think `+=` would have to do a `IF duplicated: ignore` check where the `np.add` just loops through. Any thoughts?

Thanks

D

Comment: The `+=` construction isn't sequential like `np.add.at`, it's a parallel (threaded) call to increment a set of memory locations.  That's why it can only increment anything one time (and runs the locations through `set` to assure there are no duplicates)  - otherwise those individual threads could lock as two tried to increment the same bit of memory simultaneously.

Comment: Also don't forget to mark the check if the answer is what you were looking for.

Answer (score -1):

As we do not know exactly what your data looks like it's hard to guess what the actual problem is. If this doesn't help please give an example that we can run ourselvs (i.e. without having the file `f`).

Suppose you have `x_pos = [1,1,2,3,5]`

```
a = np.zeros(10)
for i in range(len(x_pos)):
    a[x_pos[i]]+=1
# gives a = array([ 0.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

However the other code

```
a[x_pos]+=1
# gives a = array([ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

So if one of the indices occurs twice it is only updated once in the short version. Check whether this is actually the case in your xpos etc.

PS: I did a slightly easier version, with only one dimension, but the rules stay the same.

Comment: You have exactly identified the issue, thank you! Completly fixed with  suggestion 
    `np.add.at(TOF_cube, [xpos, ypos, tpos], 1)`